# How to trigger a function when 80% of the video has been reached and has been watched?

Tags: javascript, html

In short, I am struggling to figure out when the video reaches 80% AND 80% of the movie has been played in order to prevent people from fast forwarding.

I currently manage to fire a method, once the movie ends and the total value of the amount played is equal to or larger than the duration of the video.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");

var timeStarted = -1;
var timePlayed = 0;
var duration = 0;
var checkpoint = 0;
var percentage = 0.8;
var percentComplete = 0;

// If video metadata is laoded get duration
if(video.readyState > 0)
  getDuration.call(video);
//If metadata not loaded, use event to get it
else
{
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', getDuration);
}
// remember time user started the video
function videoStartedPlaying() {
  timeStarted = new Date().getTime()/1000;
}
function videoStoppedPlaying(event) {
  // Start time less then zero means stop event was fired vidout start event
  if(timeStarted>0) {
    var playedFor = new Date().getTime()/1000 - timeStarted;
    timeStarted = -1;
    // add the new ammount of seconds played
    timePlayed+=playedFor;
  }
  document.getElementById("played").innerHTML = Math.round(timePlayed)+"";
  // Count as complete only if end of video was reached
  if(timePlayed>=duration && event.type=="ended") {
    document.getElementById("status").className="complete";
  }
}

function videoIsPlaying(event) {
  if(timeStarted>0) {
    var playedFor = new Date().getTime()/1000 - timeStarted;
    timeStarted = -1;
    // add the new ammount of seconds played
    timePlayed+=playedFor;
  }
  
  checkpoint = playedFor / duration;
  percentComplete = video.currentTime / video.duration;
  
  console.log('timePlayed is '+timePlayed);
  console.log('percentComplete is '+percentComplete);
  console.log('checkpoint is '+checkpoint);
  console.log('duration is '+duration);
  console.log('playedFor is '+playedFor);
  
  if (percentComplete >= percentage && checkpoint >= percentage) {
   
  }
}

function getDuration() {
  duration = video.duration;
  document.getElementById("duration").appendChild(new Text(Math.round(duration)+""));
  console.log("Duration: ", duration);
}

video.addEventListener("play", videoStartedPlaying);
video.addEventListener("playing", videoStartedPlaying);

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", videoIsPlaying);

video.addEventListener("ended", videoStoppedPlaying);
video.addEventListener("pause", videoStoppedPlaying);
```

```css
#status span.status {
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span.status.complete {
  color: green;
}
span.status.incomplete {
  color: red;
}
#status.complete span.status.complete {
  display: inline;
}
#status.incomplete span.status.incomplete {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<video width="400" height="300" controls="true" poster="" id="video">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4"></source>
</video>

<div id="status" class="incomplete">
<span>Play status: </span>
<span class="status complete">COMPLETE</span>
<span class="status incomplete">INCOMPLETE</span>
<br />
</div>
<div>
<span id="played">0</span> seconds out of 
<span id="duration"></span> seconds. (only updates when the video pauses)
</div>
<br><br>
```

I would appreciate any hints and snippets into the right direction!

Comment: Use `timeupdate` event, see [HTML5 audio streaming: precisely measure latency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768375/html5-audio-streaming-precisely-measure-latency/38842623#38842623)

Comment: @LGSon, did you read my question and not realize that I am asking something quite different? I know how to get the currentTime and duration without the reference to your questions. I am asking for help in regard of how I can utilize such events to track how much the video has been watched in total. For example, if I rewind a 30s video at half point to the beginning and I then finish it, my `timePlayed` will reflect 45s then. @guest271314 thanks for link to your previous answer. Could you please elaborate a little more as to how I could utilize timeupdate in my case?

Comment: Where do you try to check if 80% of video has been played? Note also, if user seeks to a `0` after playing half of `duration`, current implementation still updates total duration of video played using a time range that has already been played. You can store current times within `timeupdate` event to an array, only update total time played if ranges are greater than values stored within array.

Comment: I am currently not checking for the 80%. I only have the `var checkpoint`. I checked before within `function videoStoppedPlaying`, but then realized it is not beneficial, cause the user has to pause the video (or it has to end) in order for it to work. That's when I found got aware of `timeupdate` & as you hinted, that's what I need to use. I agree, but it seems that I have a mental blockade when it comes to the implementation. https://fiddle.jshell.net/x84dsuv5/3/ I tried to check against the percentage played and percentage completed. The checkpoint outputs NaN & playedFor undefined? hmm

Comment: _"I am currently not checking for the 80%."_ Well, that is Question, yes?  Consider posting a Question including the attempt you made to check if 80% of video has been played, if the linked Questions and Answers do not resolve current Question. Will try to put together a fork of your jsfiddle using either `timeupdate` or `progress` event.

Comment: I meant to say I was not currently checking for the 80% in the question I initially asked on here as I knew the approach I was dong was wrong. The jsfiddle I linked to does check for it, but the playedFor variable is empty and that's where it currently hiccups. edit: I did update the fiddle in my question on here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `Array` and a `Set` object. At `loadedmetadata` event set value which is measurement of `.8` of `.duration` `Math.ceil(video.duration * percent)`, where `percent` is a decimal less than `1`. Use `for` loop to fill `Array` instance with values from `1` to `N`, where `N` is eighty-percent of `.duration` `+1` as an integer. Call `.add()` on `Set` instance with `Math.ceil(video.currentTime)` as parameter at `timeupdate` event. At `timeupdate` event iterate `Array`  using `.every()` to check if each element of `Set` `.has()` element of `Array`, including `Math.ceil(video.duration * percent)`, which will be eighty-percent or greater of `.duration`; if `true` is returned from `.every()` call function.

```js
const video = document.getElementById("video");
const res = new Set();
const arr = Array();
const percent = .8;
let toWatch = 0;

function mediaWatched (curr) {
  alert(`${curr}% of media watched`)
}

function handleMetadata(e) {
  toWatch = Math.ceil(video.duration * percent);
  for (let i = 1; i <= toWatch + 1; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
}

function handleTimeupdate (e) {
  res.add(Math.ceil(video.currentTime));
  if (arr.every(function(n) {return res.has(n)})) {
    console.log(video.currentTime, video.duration);
    video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeupdate);
    mediaWatched(Math.ceil((video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100));
  }
}

video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", handleMetadata);

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeupdate);
```

```html
<video width="400" height="300" controls="true" poster="" id="video">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works and lets the user know when the 80% checkmark was reached/played. But where I struggle with is that on top of it, I want to make sure that 80% has been watched and it has not been forwarded to that point. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ChrisPalmerBreuer `Set` does not allow duplicate entries. `Set.prototype.add()` is only called at `timeupdate` event. See updated post. Added check for `.length` of `.keys()` of `Set` passed to `Array.from()` which must be equal to `toWatch` for function to be called. This handles cases of fast forward, and reverse seeking.

Comment: Perfect, that sounds exactly like what I am looking for! Unfortunately, the `mediaWatched` is not called anymore. I am not too sure if I can find the hiccup as I am fairly new to JavaScript all together.

Comment: The event listener is removed. `javascript` at Answer demonstrates approach of calling a function when 80% of video is reached once. Configure the implementation to suit specific requirement. See updated post.

Comment: Great, that works. But for example, if I fast forward to around 50% length, and let it play then, it will fire whenever 80% of the movie is reached, but it shouldn't because I fast forwarded to 50% and essentially only watched 30%. Does that make sense? I need to have a `playedFor` variable that will count how many seconds have been played totally which is not equal to `currentTime`. e.g., there is a 30s video and if it was initially played to 50%, `playedFor` would equal `currentTime` and it would be 15, but then if I rewind to the beginning and watch till the end, `playedFor` would be 45

Comment: This is where I struggle figuring out how I can have a variable to keeps on adding on top of itself. If you have an idea how that could be implemented into your approach, I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 1):

[MDNs Cross-browser audio basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Cross-browser_audio_basics)

> #### timeupdate
>
> The timeupdate event is fired every time the currentTime property
> changes. In practice this occurs every 250 milliseconds. This event
> can be used to trigger the displaying of playback progress.
>
> ```
> myAudio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
>   //update something related to playback progress
> });
> ```