# Run function when audio passes a certain time point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Here is what i have:**

```
<audio id='audio' src="lol.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

and:

```
var currentTime = document.getElementById('audio').currentTime
var timePoint = 26.5

function lolz() {
document.write("lolz")
}
```

**What i want:**

I want to run the function lolz() when *currentTime* is greater than *timePoint*.

Comment: You'll need an event handler, for instance something that triggers when the audio plays. Start searching MDN

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768375/html5-audio-streaming-precisely-measure-latency/38842623#38842623

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your should make your `lolz` function an event listener by attaching it to the [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate) event.

---

### Your Updated Code:

```
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('timeupdate', lolz)
var timePoint = 26.5

function lolz () {
  if (this.currentTime > timePoint) {
    document.body.textContent = "lolz"
  }
}
```

```
<audio id="audio" src="lol.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

---

### Working Example Snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('timeupdate', lolz)
var timePoint = 3.1

function lolz () {
  if (this.currentTime > timePoint) {
    document.body.textContent = "lolz"
  }
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" src="//mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2587/AudioTest.ogg" autoplay></audio>
```