# Making an HTML5 Audio Player for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, audio

I've spent a few days digging almost any post possible on this subject.
So far I haven't been able to find a proper solution.
Basically I would like to create an HTML5 audio player that plays music (one file at a time) on mobile browsers (iOS/Android) that will play the music instantly when the user clicks "Play" (just like youtube works on mobile browsers) and that the browser won't try to load/cache the whole file first before it plays it.
I tried Audio Sprites and that didn't work well (it is mostly related to web games).

Comment: You can use the <audio> </audio> tag

Comment: See [HTML5 audio streaming: precisely measure latency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38768375/)