# Display video stream chunks on page (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, stream

I'm still new in Node.js and trying to figure out things so excuse me if I sound incoherent.

So I've read some beginner notes on streams and I'm testing it out at the moment.
I got these Seinfeld episodes (.mkv files) in my project files (public/images/videos/Seinfeld.S09E07.720p.WebRip.ReEnc-DeeJayAhmed.mkv) that I would like to show on a page. Now, the easy choice would be to just put it in the 'src' of the video tag in my ejs file.

However, I would like to stream the video parts so that it doesn't have to wait for the whole file to be ready to display the episode. I thought I could use .createReadStream for this. However, I don't know how I can transfer those little chunks of video data that are ready into my webpage to display them in my video player.

*index.js server-side*

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

    /* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/../images/videos/Seinfeld.S09E07.720p.WebRip.ReEnc-DeeJayAhmed.mkv');

    myReadStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        // no idea what to do from here
    })
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express'
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

EJS file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <video src="" type="video/mkv" autoplay controls></video>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably need to pipe the stream to the user: e.g. `myReadStream.pipe(res)`

Comment: And then how do I access the chunks?

Comment: through using what the answer below suggests...

Comment: Ok, I'll study it. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fetch()`, `Response.getReader()` which returns a `ReadableStream` and `MediaSource` at client to read the stream of response from server and append one or more `ArrayBuffer`s representing chunks of one or more media resources which can be rendered at `<video>` element, see [HTML5 audio streaming: precisely measure latency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768375/html5-audio-streaming-precisely-measure-latency/).

Comment: Ok, for now I don't understand what all that means, but I have a starting point for research with the things you mentioned. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @TijlDeclerck See [Media Source Extensions™](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/)